# Ionic Firebase Plugin not installed

Tags: angular, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I created a new ionic project and added firebase to this, but everytime I do an ionic serve -c and open the DevApp, I see in the console following errors:

- Ionic Native: tried calling Firebase.subscribe, but the Firebase plugin is not installed.
- Install the Firebase plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase'

Ionic info:

```
 ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.2 (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0
```

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)

```
Cordova Platforms     : ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.0, (and 5 other plugins)
```

System:

```
NodeJS : v8.12.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 10
```

app.component.ts:

```js
export class MyApp {
  rootPage: any = HomePage;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, public toastCtrl: ToastController, private firebase: Firebase) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();

      try {
        this.initializeFirebase();
      } catch (error) {
        this.firebase.logError(error);
      }

    });


  }

  initializeFirebase() {
    if (!this.platform.is("core")) {
      this.firebase.subscribe("all");
      this.platform.is('android') ? this.initializeFirebaseAndroid() : this.initializeFirebaseIOS();
    }
  }
  initializeFirebaseAndroid() {
    this.firebase.getToken().then(token => { });
    this.firebase.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(token => { })
    this.subscribeToPushNotifications();
  }
  initializeFirebaseIOS() {
    this.firebase.grantPermission()
      .then(() => {
        this.firebase.getToken().then(token => { });
        this.firebase.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(token => { })
        this.subscribeToPushNotifications();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.firebase.logError(error);
      });
  }
  subscribeToPushNotifications() {
    this.firebase.onNotificationOpen().subscribe((response) => {
      if (response.tap) {
        console.log(response.body);
        //Received while app in background (this should be the callback when a system notification is tapped)
        //This is empty for our app since we just needed the notification to open the app
      } else {
        console.log(response.body);
        //received while app in foreground (show a toast)
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: response.body,
          duration: 3000
        });
        toast.present();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    Firebase
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Anyone having the same problem at the moment?

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 2):

try to check *firebase cloud messaging plugin*

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated
```

perhaps *double check google-services.json location*

```
projects\src\app\google-services.json
```

and at the end re-add *android and check plugins*

```
ionic repair
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - check out what Cordova version you use and update it to match project dependency requirements (i.e. `npm install -g cordova@9.0.0`).

---

Most likely the version of the build tool being used (Cordova) is not compatible with the package (plugin) that needs to be used.

I had similar issue with `cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics` running Cordova 8.1. It looked like it was work well on Android but did not work as expected on iOS. While debugging, I was able to detect errors in the console's error log such as

> tried calling [method] but the FirebaseAnalytics plugin is not
> installed

Re-adding the iOS platform having the `--verbose` flag included showed following:

> Installing "cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics" for ios
> Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova version. cordova: 8.1.1, failed version requirement: >=9.0.0

After installing the at least minimum supported version (9.0.0) and rebuilding the iOS platform (remove platform, add platform, prepare/run/emulate iOS build), the issue was resolved.

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing same problem, then I tried FCM instead of Firebase.

I will suggest you use FCM for the same. It is working fine for me.

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebase
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated
npm install @ionic-native/fcm
```

Comment: I got plugin not installed error in the console,I have remove platform then again add but erro not removed that me sir what I do?

Comment: 1. This plugin will work only on the device.
2. Again use that command to add the plugin.
3. Call the plugin when platform will be ready.

Comment: 1. I  have tested in device only 2. tried 2 time but same result.3. already called inside ready function

Comment: Which OS are you using

Comment: i am using mac machine

Comment: sir i have fixed above issue.

Answer (score -2):

You have to add firebase to your project app module, under `provider`. You would likely need to do this for any plugin you install in the future as well.

If you are using Ionic3, it's the file `app.module.ts`.

Comment: Have you run this command `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase`?
If it doesn't work try to run `ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebase` then add the plugin again.

Comment: Do you have the `google-services.json` file in  your root folder?

Comment: Yes both for Android and iOS are added.

Answer (score -2):

Use `platform.ready()` function before using the object of the imported class:

```
constructor(public qrScanner: QRScanner) {
                // solve the problem - "plugin not installed".
                platform.ready().then(()=>{
                  this.qrscanner();
                })

}
```